# How to perform the async function before printt function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class

I don't want to call the async function in the render. I just want it to run before the printt function is called so that this.numbers get a newvalue.

Please guide me I am new to react and having trouble resolving this.
Thanks:)

```
import Box from './Box';

class EmergencyContacts extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      numbers: "default",
      loading: false
    };
       
  }


  async componentDidMount(){
    let url= "http://emergencynumberapi.com/api/country/PK";
    let data1= await fetch(url);
    let data= await data1.json();
    //let data=  await (await fetch("http://emergencynumberapi.com/api/country/UK")).json();
    this.setState({numbers: data.data},() => {
      console.log(this.state.numbers);
      console.log(this.state.numbers.country.name)
    });
  }

  printt(){
    return(<div>
      <p>hello</p>
  <Box name={this.state.numbers.country.name} code={this.state.numbers.country.ISOcode}
      numcode={this.state.numbers.country.ISOnumeric}
      amb={this.state.numbers.ambulance.all}
      fire={this.state.numbers.fire.all}
      pol={this.state.numbers.police.all}
      dispatch={this.state.numbers.dispatch.all}/></div>);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 style={{padding:"70px", backgroundColor:"white"}}>Emergency Contacts</h3>
        <div className='row' style={{padding:"10px"}}>
            <div className='col-md-2' >
             {this.printt()}
              </div>
          
          
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EmergencyContacts;
```

Comment: instead of `printt=()=>{` should be something like `printt() {`

Comment: You are not using the `loading` state. You should set the `loading` to `before you make a request and set it to `false` when you successfully get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Your component will render the first time right after mounting, before the asynchronous function is done. There's no way to avoid that. You will to need to be able to render something while it is still loading, only after it's done loading and you set the state it'll render again - now with the data. So you just need to make your `print` method return some loading indicator while the data is not yet there:

```
printt() {
  if (this.state.numbers == 'default') {
    return <p>Loading…</p>;
  } else {
    return <div>
      <p>hello</p>
  <Box name={this.state.numbers.country.name} code={this.state.numbers.country.ISOcode}
      numcode={this.state.numbers.country.ISOnumeric}
      amb={this.state.numbers.ambulance.all}
      fire={this.state.numbers.fire.all}
      pol={this.state.numbers.police.all}
      dispatch={this.state.numbers.dispatch.all}/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```